# javascript countdown timer issue when using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html

Countdown timer does not load - only after a page refresh.

I have tested the code on codepen.io etc, though when hosted on a site, the countdown does not appear, it only appears only after doing a refresh.

When I used `setInterval()` it works fine, however I want to update the countdown only once since its a days countdown, hence the use of`setTimeout()`.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setTimeout(function() {

    // Get date
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " days left ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearTimeout(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 300);
```

full code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQzMdG

Comment: setTimeout fires exactly ONCE

Comment: You are not updating the countdown every 1 second - is that comment incorrect? Your delay is 300 milliseconds, and since you are using `setTimeout()`, you are not even checking every 300ms. You are just executing the code once after 300ms has passed since loading. I don't see the point of using `setTimeout()` in this context at all - could you explain why you need the 300ms delay?

Comment: the comment is incorrect, apologies

Comment: @JaromandaX yes thats correct, however, I am not sure why it doesn't run when a user visits the page automatically?
to clarify by example:user goes to page A, sees no countdown, hits refresh, countdown appears. not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: oh, you mean the user doesn't see "23 days" or whatever it was? because I did

Comment: @JaromandaX , that's correct, the user does not see it without refreshing the page. Though when running the same code on penio, it displays fine like you mentioned.

Comment: so, the problem is that your code on *actual site* is somehow different to what you present here - have you checked the **developer** tools console in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `data-attribute`, i.e: `updateCountdown`.  That would be the flag to update the countdown only once.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get date
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (!demo.dataset.updateCountdown) {
    console.log('Update countdown.');
    demo.dataset.updateCountdown = false;
       
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    demo.innerHTML = days + " days left ";
  }

  console.log(x)
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<span id='demo'></span>
```

See? now it was updated only once.

## Resource

- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: OP said he only wanted it to be called once, hence why he was not using `setInterval`.

Comment: This answer is correct. The OP should see how it applied by re-reading the explanation and reasoning about what *else* it means is true, which could possibly be expanded in the answer.